# Validate old Password in Symfony 2 form

Tags: validation, symfony, passwords, symfony-forms

Huston, I have a problem :)

I need to validate old password.

Symfony has built in password validator, that is great but... I need to reconfigure encoding system.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints as SecurityAssert;

/**
 * User
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{

     /**
     * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword()
     */
     protected $oldPassword;
```

This return always false because password is encrypted with mcrypt.

I had tried to edit this class

```
class UserPasswordValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $encoderFactory;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate($password, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        $encoder = new CryptPasswordEncoder();

        $oldPass = $user->getPassword();

        if ($encoder->isPasswordValid($oldPass, $password, '')) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('%string%', $password)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }

}
```

But when I submit validated value $password is always **null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had make some walk around.

I look for old password in controller and check with encoder if password is valid. if it is not I make error with **flashBag** message above **form_widget**

```
  public function editProfileAction(Request $request) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $oldPassword = $user->getPassword();
```

I had to store **old password in variable before validating form** because it is overridden after **validating form.**

```
        $section = $request->get('section');

        if ($section == 'password-change') {
            $formType = EditPasswordFormType::class;
            $form = $this->createForm($formType, $user);

            $data['form'] = $form->createView();
         }


        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                if ($section == 'password-change') {
                    $data = $form->getData();
                    $encoder = new CryptPasswordEncoder();

                    $valid = $encoder->isPasswordValid($oldPassword, $data->oldPassword, '');

                    if (!$valid) {
                        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('notValidError', 'You are insert wrong old password');
                        return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
                    }
                    $ps->changePassword($user, $form);

                    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('success', 'Password Changed');
                    return $this->redirect($request->getUri());

                }

            } else {
                $data['form'] = $form->createView();
            }

        }


        return $this->render('@SciProfile/EditProfile/editProfile.html.twig', $data);
    }
```

This is twig side

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px">
    <div class="columns large-4 content-right">
        {{ form_label(form.oldPassword) }}
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-6 content-middle">
        {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notValidError') %}
            <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius">
                {{ flashMessage }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form_widget(form.oldPassword) }}
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-2"></div>
</div>
```